# How to extract kernel symbols from uImage (arm)?

Tags: gdb, kernel, arm, system-calls, u-boot

I want to extract kernel symbols from a *u-boot image*

The final goal is to debug syscalls with **gdb**

---

The kernel is compiled with `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y` and **gcc** is using **-g** option (I checked)

After `make uImage`, I've :

```
# file arch/arm/boot/*
arch/arm/boot/bootp:           directory
arch/arm/boot/compressed:      directory
arch/arm/boot/Image:           data
arch/arm/boot/install.sh:      POSIX shell script text executable
arch/arm/boot/Makefile:        ASCII English text
arch/arm/boot/uImage:          u-boot legacy uImage, Linux-3.0.6, Linux/ARM, OS Kernel Image (Not compressed), 3044476 bytes, Thu Mar 22 18:13:40 2012, Load Address: 0x00008000, Entry Point: 0x00008000, Header CRC: 0xF689B805, Data CRC: 0x6BFE76DF
arch/arm/boot/zImage:          data
```

**gdb** cannot load **uImage** directly

---

I tried this script http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=901152.

```
# file arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/*
arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/decompression_code:     data
arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/initramfs.cpio+part3:   data
arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/kernel.img:             data
arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/padding_piggy:          data
arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/piggy:                  data
arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/piggy.gz:               gzip compressed data, from Unix, max compression
arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/piggy.gz+piggy_trailer: gzip compressed data, from Unix, max compression
arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/piggy_trailer:          data
arch/arm/boot/zImage_unpacked/sizes:                  ASCII text
```

**kernel.img** is not loadable by **gdb**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `make vmlinux`. I believe GDB can read that, but it's a long time and a lot of kernel versions since I tried.

EDIT: Oh, I should say, both vmlinux and uImage should be the same but packaged differently. If that's not the case, then this won't work.

Comment: I know have a new issue due to gdbserver, but kernel symbols are correctly loaded, thanks.